# <a> inside <button> color text is not right Semantic UI

Tags: php, button, anchor, semantic-ui

I have this code:

```
<button class="ui right floated small primary labeled icon button">
    <i class="user icon"></i>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/c_contact/add_contact">Add Contact</a>
</button>
```

The image below shows that the primary class is not taking effect to the text inside the anchor tag. I went through the docs and is no class to to change the text to white either anchor buttons.

[image: Button below; icon takes the primary class but the text doesn't]

It is any way Semantic UI handles anchor buttons or I have to solve this issue with custom CSS?

Comment: This is definitely something you will have to add some custom css to. `button a { color:white; }`

Comment: Would be nice to add this feature to the framework since anchor tags are often used by php developers. Bootstrap framework has the "anchor-button" feature.

Comment: I agree...but for now, you need to implement it yourself :/

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code to this instead

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/c_contact/add_contact">
    <button class="ui right floated small primary labeled icon button">
        <i class="user icon"></i>
        Add Contact
    </button>
</a>
```